# Hibernate one to many, не связываются таблицы

Tags: java, hibernate

Здравствуйте, делаю связь таблиц на Hibernate, один учитель к многим ученикам.

Учитель:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "teacher")
    public class Teacher implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
        private Set<Pupil> pupils = new HashSet<>();
        // геттеры сеттеры
    }
```

Ученик:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pupil")
public class Pupil implements  Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id ;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;
}
```

Потом создаю учителя и пару учеников, кладу учеников в учителя и сохраняю учителя.  То есть:

```
        // сервис
        ObjectDao objectDao = new ObjectDao();

        // создаю учителя
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
        teacher.setName("teacher name");

        // создаю ученика
        Pupil pupil = new Pupil();
        pupil.setName("pupil name");

        // кладу ученика в учителя
        teacher.getPupils().add(pupil);

        // сохраняю учителя.
        objectDao.saveObject(teacher);
```

Результат:

```
mysql> select * from teacher;
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | teacher name |
+----+--------------+

mysql> select * from pupil;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | name       | teacher_id |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | pupil name |       NULL |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня в ученике ID учителя null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По просьбе  Nicolas Chabanovsky более развернуто.

Отцы–основатели Hibernate CHRISTIAN BAUER, GAVIN KING и GARY GREGORY
в своей книге Java Persistence with Hibernate SECOND EDITION 2016г (https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate-second-edition) пишут (далее два отрывка в моем переводе на русский)

(стр. 43-44)

> The basic procedure for linking a Bid with an Item...
>
> Основная процедура для соединения Bid и Item выглядит следующим образом:
>
> •  anItem.getBids().add(aBid);
>
> •  aBid.setItem(anItem);
>
> Когда Вы создаете двунаправленную связь, требуются  два действия:
>
> •  Вы должны добавить Bid в bids - коллекцию Item.
>
> •  item свойство Bid должно быть установлено.
>
> JPA не поддерживает (doesn’t manage) персистные связи.
> Если Вы хотите манипулировать связями, Вы должны делать так, как если бы Вы работали без Hibernate.
> Если у вас двунаправленная связь, Вы должны позаботиться о двух сторонах связи.  Если Вы до сих пор не поняли, то спросите себя “Что бы я сделал без Hibernate?”

Далее  в пункте 7.3.3.

> The following code creates...
>
> Cледующий код создает новый Item и новый Bid и затем соединяет их.
>
> Item someItem = new Item("Some Item");
>
> Bid someBid = new Bid(new BigDecimal("123.00"), someItem);
>
> someItem.getBids().add(someBid);              <-- Don’t forget!
>
> Вы должны позаботиться о двух сторонах связи: Bid конструктор устанавливает ссылку на item. Для поддержки целостности в памяти вы должны добавить bid в список деталей у Item. Теперь связь с точки зрения кода Java полная, все ссылки установлены.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте перед сохранением добавить учителя ученику:

```
pupil.setTeacher(teacher);
```

Answer (score 0):

HIBERNATE (и JPA) при операциях обновления данных (не при загрузке данных) никак не поддерживают мастер-детальные связи. В частности, при создании детали надо вручную прописать у детали ссылку на мастера и включить деталь в список мастера.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?