# hibernate mapping xml добавление в таблицу

Tags: java, hibernate

Допустим у меня есть Два объекта
: Пенал и ручка
в пенале может содержаться большое количество ручек представим бд с двумя таблицами:
Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping">
    <class name="ru.modelsxml.Pinal" table="Pinal">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name"/>
         <bag name="ruchka" table="ruchka" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="name_ruchka" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="ru.modelsxml.Ruchka"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Код:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping">
<class name="ru.modelsxml.Ruchka" table="ruchka">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name_ruchka" column="name_ruchka"/>
    <many-to-one name="pinal" column="pinal_id" class="ru.modelsxml.Pinal"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

и вот я сразу создаю объект пенал, который содержит несколько ручек и через hibernate пытаюсь добавить его в БД в результате 1 пенал добавился и ручки добавились, но в таблице ручек у ручек не проставляются id пеналов к которым они принадлежат. вопрос: какой чащё надо параметр указать чтобы у ручек проставлялись грамотно id пеналов с которыми они добавляются? или неужели добавлять в бд сначало пеналы, потом получать id пеналов добавлять эти id в модель ручек и потом добавлять ручки в бд?

```
import java.util.List;

public class Pinal {
    private  String name;
    private List<Ruchki> ruchkis;

    public List<Ruchki> getRuchkis() {
        return ruchkis;
    }

    public void setRuchkis(List<Ruchki> ruchkis) {
        this.ruchkis = ruchkis;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}



public class Ruchki {
    private String name;
    private Pinal pinal;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Pinal getPinal() {
        return pinal;
    }

    public void setPinal(Pinal pinal) {
        this.pinal = pinal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Предоставили бы код, которым создаете пенал с ручками, может кто и помог бы. 0) `penal = new Penal(); ruchka = new Ruchka();` 1) `ruchka.setPenal(penal);` 2) `penal.getRuchkis().add(ruchka);` 3) `em.persist(penal);` т.е. надо устанвить связи в обоих направлениях (пп1 и 2)

Comment: приведу пример: изначально у меня прилетает json  строка  в которой содержится название пинала, и список ручек : String json = "{\"name\":\"pinal\", \"ruchkis\":[{\"name\":\"ruchka1\"}, {\"name\":\"ruchka2\"}]}";   и в json  у ручек не прописан id  пинала, т.к. мы не знаем ещё id пинала и он генерируется базой по этому  приходит именно такая строка теперь я говорю  Pinal pinal = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Pinal.class);
так я получил объект пинал с ручками и когда я добавляю его в бд то в таблице ручек не прописывается id  пинала к которому они принадлежат session.save(pinal);

Comment: и разве в `bag`-е у пинала `key column` должен быть `ruchka_name`, а не `pinal_id`?

Comment: Должна быть pinal_id. Да это я ошибся поторопился приводя пример но. Всеравно. Id пинала у ручек не сохраняется

Comment: В любом случае парсер json может не быть таким сообразительным, чтобы в ручках установить ссылки на пинал. А именно ручка является хозяином связи и в базу пишется то значение, которое у ручки. А оно как раз null. Т.е. ручка должна ссылаться на пинал

Comment: Hibernate не делает, то что Вы хотите в данном вопросе. См. также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559223/hibernate-one-to-many-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/567167#567167